# How to hide Div in a proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

In my Asp web application, I have following HTML divs, I need to hide those div by clicking `<a>` tag.

```js
function showHide() {
  var viewProductServiceDiv = document.getElementById("psDiv");
  var psbGrid = document.getElementById("psbGrid");
  var filterDiv = document.getElementById("filterDiv");
  if (viewProductServiceDiv.style.display === "none") {

    psbGrid.style.display = "none";
    filterDiv.style.display = "none";
    viewProductServiceDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    psbGrid.style.display = "block";
    filterDiv.style.display = "block";
    viewProductServiceDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row search-row form-inline" id="filterDiv">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
      <a href="#" onclick="showHide(); return false;" style="text-decoration:underline">Show/Hide Divs</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row grid-row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="psbGrid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="psDiv">
        <button id="backto" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code works fine, but looking ugly and I think this is not the good coding practices. Have any possible way to improve this good code. Can I use the JQuery to do this? then how?

And I also need to hide `psDiv` and show other two divs ( `filterDiv , psbGrid` ) when clicking the Back button.What is the best way to do this.

**simply says, I need to hide `filterDiv`, `psbGrid` divs by clicking `<a>` tag and need show those two divs again when click backbutton and need to hide `psDiv` div**

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using a JS framework like JQuery?

Comment: in jquery you could use [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Hi mate, can you tell me which divs are you trying to hide by clicking the "a" tags?
Also, check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sarbraj/3ky0xv94/4/

Comment: @SarbrajDulai I need to hide `filterDiv, psbGrid` divs by clicking `<a>` tag and need show again when click backbutton

Comment: @SarbrajDulai its not working

Comment: So let me get this straight, the behaviour you are trying to achieve is when you click Show/Hide Divs, it disappears and when you click the back button, Show/Hide Divs appear again?

Answer (score 0):

You can target the next element by finding the closest `.row`, then toggle a class on the element:

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.row').toggleClass('hideContent');
  $(this).closest('.row').next().find('#psbGrid').toggleClass('hideContent');
  $(this).closest('.row').next().find('#psDiv').toggleClass('hideContent');
});
$('#backto').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.row').prev().toggleClass('hideContent');
  $(this).closest('.row').find('#psbGrid').toggleClass('hideContent');
  $(this).closest('#psDiv').toggleClass('hideContent');
});
```

```css
.hideContent{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row search-row form-inline" id="filterDiv">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline">Show/Hide Divs</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row grid-row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="psbGrid">
        psb Grid
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="psDiv" class="hideContent">
        <button id="backto" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply says I need to hide `filterDiv, psbGrid` divs by clicking `<a>` tag and need to show those two divs again when clicking back button and need to hide `psDiv` div when clicking back button

Comment: @Adam, what if clicking on `Show/Hide Divs` second time?

Comment: Nothing need to happen, its my mistake.

Comment: @Adam, I think you do not need to hide the button, please check the updated answer:)

Comment: yeah its okay but when I clicking back button `psDiv` need to hide (which means back button also need to hide,coz its in inside the `psDiv`) and only show `filterDiv, psbGrid` then again I click `<a>` , these two divs `filterDiv, psbGrid` need to hide and `psDiv` need to show.

Comment: @Adam, try the updated answer, please notice *psDiv* will be hidden on page load:)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need jquery it's working with   `viewProductServiceDiv.classList.toggle("toggleCls");` method.

```
<style>
        .toggleCls {
          display:none;
        }

        </style>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row search-row form-inline" id="filterDiv">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                      <a href="#"  onclick="showHide();" style="text-decoration:underline">Show/Hide Divs</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row grid-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div id="psbGrid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div id="psDiv">
                            <button id="backto" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function showHide() {

            var viewProductServiceDiv = document.getElementById("psDiv");
            var psbGrid = document.getElementById("psbGrid");
            var filterDiv = document.getElementById("filterDiv");
            viewProductServiceDiv.classList.toggle("toggleCls");
        }
        </script>
```

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/ptxdsvwn/7/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be by using jQuery and doing something like this

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $("#filterDiv, #psbGrid").hide();
});

$('#backto').click(function(){
    $("#filterDiv, #psbGrid").show();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sarbraj/3ky0xv94/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.You need to include jQuery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function HideDiv() 
{
   $("#filterDiv").hide();
   $("#psbGrid").hide();
   $("#psDiv").show();
}
function ShowDiv()
{
   $("#filterDiv").show();
   $("#psbGrid").show();
   $("#psDiv").hide();
}
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row search-row form-inline" id="filterDiv">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
      <a href="#" onclick="HideDiv();" style="text-decoration:underline">Show/Hide 
       Divs</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row grid-row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="psbGrid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="psDiv" style="display:none">
        <button id="backto" onclick="ShowDiv();"  class="btn btn- 
        default">Back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```